# How to simulate a F10 function key press in java so that it carries out windows function related to that button

Tags: java, windows, keypress, awtrobot

I am trying to write a cool program that will turn my backlit keyboard on and off based upon the time of day. I thought I could do this by simply simulating a F10 keypress using robot as this is the button on the keyboard that turns the backlights on and off:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class Backlit{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    //if need to turn on/off backlit keyboard
      // Simulate a F10 key press
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
  }
}
```

However this does not actually affect the backlights. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this or a different way of doing it?

Edit: I think that my issue is that although I have my keyboard set to not require the fn button to be held when the F10 button is pressed, this is not applied to the virtual presses as the function that is carried out when the button is pressed without fn is what actually happens. However I cannot find a VK code for fn?

Comment: There is software external to Java that is capturing the "backlight" keypress. This code should press the key correctly.

Comment: Have you looked for documentation on your keyboard vendor's website?

Comment: I think that my issue is that although I have my keyboard set to not require the fn button to be held when the F10 button is pressed, this is not applied to the virtual presses as the function that is carried out when the button is pressed without fn is what actually happens. However I cannot find a VK code for fn?

Comment: It's probably a custom VK code. Best bet is to write or find a small program that will hook keypresses and display the VK code, then press the button.